# javascript slider arrow keys and fade image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I managed to get a simple image slider exactly how I wanted it, styling it with css grids that I'm learning too.

I didn't manage to do 2 things I'd like to achieve:

1. Use arrow keys of the keyboard to change the "big image" as one can already do by clicking on thumbnails.
2. make the main image appear with a short transition fade effect.

Here is the code and javacript I already have, css is on another file:

```js
var lastImg = 1; //Set initial thumbnail and preview
document.getElementById(0).src = document.getElementById(lastImg).src;
document.getElementById(lastImg).className = "thumb selected";

function preview(img) {
  document.getElementById(lastImg).className = "thumb normal";
  img.className = "thumb selected";
  document.getElementById(0).src = img.src;
  lastImg = img.id
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 6px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

.nom {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 3/8;
  grid-row: 1;
  color: #f9423ab5;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 3.2vw;
  align-self: center;
  animation: couleur 8s;
}

a {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
}

.accueil {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 10;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.contact {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 11;
  grid-row: 1;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: coral;
}

.bigimage {
  width: 61vw;
  grid-column: 3/11;
  grid-row: 2/5;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.thumb {
  width: 3vw;
  height: 2vw;
  margin-left: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  align-self: center;
}

.thumb:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.thumbnails {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 2/5;
  margin-top: 16px;
}
```

```html
<img id="0" class="preview normal bigimage" />

<div class="thumbnails">
  <img id="1" class="thumb normal" src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100?text=image1" alt="image1" onclick="preview(this)" />
  <img id="2" class="thumb normal" src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100?text=image2" alt="image2" onclick="preview(this)" />
  <img id="3" class="thumb normal" src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100?text=image3" alt="image3" onclick="preview(this)" />


</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. You can add images from lorempixel or placeholder.com - your use the word transition fade effect, why not google that?

Comment: Also I do not recommend to use numeric IDs. Instead use "image0" through "image15" for example

Comment: Thanks mplungjan for helping me posting my question here, ;-)!

Comment: Please add images from the net (placeholder) and update the snippet with your css

Comment: Excuse me but what's the use to add images here with placeholder.com?

Comment: To create a [mcve] - so we do not have to guess if your slider works or not

Comment: I'm new here and I can't even find how to change my snippet to add my css, and I don't know how to use placeholder.com. I'm not a professional developper or geek, just curious to create things on the web myself, the way I want it. I just needed help with details with javascript functions. Anyway, thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53804205/edit) - scroll down, click _edit the above snippet_, open another tab, go to placeholder.com, use the sizer to make images of the appropriate size. Go back and change the URLs in the src `https://via.placeholder.com/140x100?text=image1` for example and add the missing CSS in the CSS frame

Comment: Thanks for your help "mplungjan", I did it and erased some images for more clarity.

Comment: But you did not update the correct snippet

Comment: Anyway you got an answer

Comment: Now I updated your corrected version, ;-). I have a big part of the answer and it's cool! I still don't know how to make images fade a little when the main image changes when clicking on thumbnail or pressing arrow keys.

Comment: That could be a new question. Search for transition on click first

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it with those words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var lastImg = 'image1'; //Set initial thumbnail and preview
document.getElementById('image0').src = document.getElementById(lastImg).src;
document.getElementById(lastImg).className = "thumb selected";

function preview(img) {
  document.getElementById(lastImg).className = "thumb normal";
  img.className = "thumb selected";
  document.getElementById('image0').src = img.src;
  lastImg = img.id;
}

function previewOnKey(e) {
    /* left key */
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        var previousImg = document.getElementById(lastImg).previousElementSibling;
        if (previousImg) {
            preview(previousImg);
        }
    }

    /* right key */
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        var nextImg = document.getElementById(lastImg).nextElementSibling;
        if (nextImg) {
            preview(nextImg);
        }
    }
}

document.onkeydown = previewOnKey;
```

```html
<img id="image0" class="preview normal bigimage" />

<div class="thumbnails">
  <img id="image1" class="thumb normal" src="https://placekitten.com/g/150/80" alt="image1" onclick="preview(this)"/>
  <img id="image2" class="thumb normal" src="https://placekitten.com/g/151/80" alt="image2" onclick="preview(this)" />
  <img id="image3" class="thumb normal" src="https://placekitten.com/g/152/80" alt="image3" onclick="preview(this)" />
 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot "IIona K" for the time spent to write and send this code, it works fine and  I can now also circulate between images with key arrows. :-))